# Как написать код, который при пересечение 2 цветов даёт третий цвет?

Tags: java, алгоритм, javafx

Есть окружность с чёрным контуром, к ней мышью подношу окружность серого цвета. Там где фигуры пересекаются (то есть серый пиксель наехал на чёрный), код должен изменять цвет этого пикселя на красный.

Подскажите, как это реализовать.

Интересует именно пересечение цветов, математические методы пересечения окружностей не подходят, так как вместо окружностей могут быть другие фигуры. Окружности я взял как пример.

Пример того, о чём я говорю: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lc13SUZPkqQ

Вот как я создаю окружность:

```
            int radius = 25;
            int strokeWidth = 1;
            Color strokeColor = Color.BLACK;

            Circle circle1 = new Circle(event.getX(), event.getY(), radius, Color.YELLOW);
            circle1.setStroke(strokeColor);
            circle1.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);

            mainScene.getChildren().addAll(circle1);
```

Comment: Приведите пример кода, что конкретно Вам не удается. Приведите пример как программа работает и как должна работать, т.е. "вот так и так происходит", а "вот так и так ожидаемо". Можете подробнее почитать [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: У меня есть AnchorPane, на которой я могу создать две окружности разных цветов. На этом мой код закончился. У меня не получается (точнее я не знаю, как это сделать) написать код, который найдёт пересечение окружности с чёрным контуров, с окружность с серым контуром.

Comment: Если кратко: узнаем центры окружностей( `getCenterX/*Y*/()`) и радиус; математически определяем пересекаются ли; если да - рисуем поверх всего красный `SVGPath` нужной формы в нужном месте

Comment: Я вас понял, но если это будут не 2 окружность, а окружность и семиугольник? Я именно хотел узнать про пересечение цветов)

Comment: Я простого способа не знаю( ну кроме использования альфа канала, правда цвет не будет произвольным )

Comment: Спасибо, не когда не слышал про альфа канал) В качестве примера того, что я имел ввиду:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lc13SUZPkqQ

Comment: Единственное, что мне вообще приходит в голову - это уходить в сторону OpenGL. Иначе придется ваять все вручную. Могу только посоветовать Вам копать в сторону этой библиотеки и рисовать с ее помощью. Она в принципе сама умеет оочень много и Вам не придется изобретать велосипед.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Попробую с OpenGL